# AllowTcp in ssh function

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, tor

I'm trying to set up a tor node following http://sickbits.net/creating-a-personal-privoxytorproxy-ec2-instance/ using ubuntu 14.4 lts on ec2. I've gotten to:

```
$ grep AllowTcp /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AllowTcpForwarding yes
$ sudo service ssh restart
```

when I run :

```
$ grep AllowTcp /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I get a blank line showing that this does not exist, I confirmed this by checking visually. Should I just add the line in or is this a mistake?

Comment: You can add the line manually and then check the availability again after restarting `ssh`.

Comment: I've added the line, restarted and confirmed it with the grep. what do you mean by "check the availability" ? - Thanks, Bill

Comment: Does the output of `grep` showing the line now?

Comment: yes, I can see it now.

Comment: Then you are good :)

Comment: Answer given...

Comment: To be noted: AllowTCPForwarding is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the line manually to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

If the line were there before restarting, then it should be there after restarting too unless something has been done in the meantime or the restarting (stop-start) the service itself removes the line. In your case the the line should be there after restarting `ssh`.

If any invalid line is added to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, then `ssh` won't start after being stopped i.e. when you do `sudo service ssh restart`, `ssh` service will stop at first and then while starting it will read the configuration file and find an invalid line, then it would simply just stay stopped. You then need to delete the invalid line to start `ssh` service again.

Comment: I think what you are saying is that after I added the line and restarted, if the line was invalid it would have been deleted from the file?

Comment: @user61629: Please check my edits in the answer..